# What's the Simplest Way to Override/Rewrite the %category% Permalink Structure Tag?

Tags: categories, filters, rewrite-rules

See: https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/

By default, when someone sets their permalink structure to:

`/%category%/%postname%/`

Post URLs appear like so:

https://example.com/**abc**/some-cool-post/

*ABC* merely represents the first category of potentially several selected for the post, but unlikely the most appropriate.

I've made it so that my writers can select which category should be most prominent, which is saved as post meta for each post, and can be output with the variable `$prominent_category`.

I would like to automatically replace `%category%` with `$prominent_category` in the slug, without the need of registering an additional taxonomy or doing anything else that might be overkill, so that whatever the author sets as their prominent category, say *Pizza*, that the new structure for the post appears as so:

https://example.com/**pizza**/some-cool-post/

Are either `category_rewrite_rules` or `post_link_category` the right choice, or should I be going down a different path?

---

```
if ( $prominent_category = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'prominent_cat', true ) ) {
echo esc_html( str_replace( ' ', '-', strtolower( $prominent_category ) ) );
}
```

---

Full attempt:

```
add_filter( 'post_link_category', 'prominent_link_category', 10, 3 );
function prominent_link_category( $cat, $cats, $post ) {
if ( $prominent_primary_cat = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'prominent_primary', true ) ) {
$cat = get_term_by( 'name', esc_html( str_replace( ' ', '-', strtolower( $prominent_primary_cat ) ) ), 'category' );
} else {
$category = get_the_category();
$cat = esc_attr( $category[0]->cat_slug );
}
return $cat;
}
```

Comment: Is `$prominent_category` a *global* variable; if so, where/when/how is it defined? Or is `prominent_category` the *meta key*? But yes, you'd want to use the `post_link_category` hook to filter the `%category%` replacement value.

Comment: So does the metadata `prominent_cat` contain the category name (e.g. `foo cat`), slug (e.g. `foo-cat`) or ID (e.g. `123`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the [`post_link_category` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_link_category/) is indeed what you would use to filter the `%category%` replacement value in the permalink.

And here's an example with `prominent_cat` being the meta key and the value being the category name (e.g. `Pizza Hut`), where I'm using [`get_term_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/) to get the category object/data:

```php
add_filter( 'post_link_category', 'my_post_link_category', 10, 3 );
function my_post_link_category( $cat, $cats, $post ) {
    $prominent_category = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'prominent_cat', true );
    if ( $term = get_term_by( 'name', $prominent_category, 'category' ) ) {
        $cat = $term;
    }

    return $cat;
}
```

If the meta value is a term/category ID, then you can simply use [`get_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term/) to get the category data:

```php
add_filter( 'post_link_category', 'my_post_link_category', 10, 3 );
function my_post_link_category( $cat, $cats, $post ) {
    $prominent_category = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'prominent_cat', true );
    if ( $prominent_category && term_exists( (int) $prominent_category ) ) {
        $cat = get_term( $prominent_category );
    }

    return $cat;
}
```

Comment: Try again with my *first* example: copy the exact code, paste it into the theme `functions.php` file, and change the meta key (I see you used `pc_primary` in the question). Also, yes, the `else` part isn't needed since WordPress already did that which the value is the one you're changing/filtering. Additionally, instead of `get_the_ID()`, you should use `$post->ID`.